# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.dataSource')

Tags: react-native

run on android emulator but undefined is not an object (evaluating 'thia.state.dataSource') pls help me, what is wrong ? could you help me undefined is not an object (evaluating 'thia.state.dataSource') undefined is not an object (evaluating 'thia.state.dataSource') undefined is not an object (evaluating 'thia.state.dataSource') undefined is not an object (evaluating 'thia.state.dataSource')

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Button,
    ListView,
    TouchableHighlight,
    Alert,
} from 'react-native';

export default class deneme1 extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        var ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
        this.state = {
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([])
        };
    }


    componentDidMount() {

        var tit = [];
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200)) {
                var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

                for (var i = 0; i < response.movies.length; i++) {
                    tit.push(response.movies[i].title);
                }
                Alert.alert(tit.toString());
                this.setState({
                    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(tit)
                })
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET", 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json', true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ListView
                    enableEmptySections={true}
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={this.renderRow} />
            </View>
        );
    }

    renderRow(dataRow) {
        <TouchableHighlight>
            <View>
                <Text>
                    {dataRow}
                </Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    on: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    },
    off: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        backgroundColor: 'black',
    },
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
    },
    instructions: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#333333',
        marginBottom: 5,
    },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('deneme1', () => deneme1);
```

Comment: May be it is a typo? It should be `this` instead of `thia`

Comment: actually , doesnt set data source like this,

this.setState ({
dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2'])
}) 
  
constructor() {
    super();
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
 
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([])
    };
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I copied and ran your code and fixed errors you had.
This is the code without errors:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Button,
    ListView,
    TouchableHighlight,
    Alert,
} from 'react-native';

export default class deneme1 extends Component {
     constructor() {
         super();

         var ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
         this.state = {
             dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([])
         };
     }


     componentDidMount() {
         var tit = [];
         var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {

             if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200)) {
                 var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

                 for (var i = 0; i < response.movies.length; i++) {
                     tit.push(response.movies[i].title);
                 }
                 Alert.alert(tit.toString());
                 this.setState({
                     dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(tit)
                 })
             }
         }

         xmlhttp.open("GET", 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json', true);
         xmlhttp.send();
     }


     render() {
         return (
             <View style={styles.container}>
                 <ListView
                     enableEmptySections={true}
                     dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                     renderRow={this.renderRow} />
             </View>
         );
     }

     renderRow(dataRow) {
         return <TouchableHighlight>
             <View>
                 <Text>
                     {dataRow}
                 </Text>
             </View>
         </TouchableHighlight>
     }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     on: {
         width: 100,
         height: 100,
         backgroundColor: 'yellow',
     },
     off: {
         width: 100,
         height: 100,
         backgroundColor: 'black',
     },
     container: {
         flex: 1,
         justifyContent: 'center',
         alignItems: 'center',
         backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
     },
     welcome: {
         fontSize: 20,
         textAlign: 'center',
         margin: 10,
     },
     instructions: {
         textAlign: 'center',
         color: '#333333',
         marginBottom: 5,
     },
 });

AppRegistry.registerComponent('deneme1', () => deneme1);
```

There were 2 errors.

1.) In the componentDidMount you assigned a function to the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` property, and inside that function you are using `this` keyword. But since `this` was not bound to the proper context, you got your undefined error on this line:

```
this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(tit)
})
```

To bind the `this` to the function I used arrow function as you can see in the code. For more explanation [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback).

2.) You forgot `return` keyword inside `renderRow` function.